# Determine whether $\int_1^\infty \sin \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx $ is divergent or convergent

Tags: calculus

> $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \sin \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx $

I tried to use substitution to integrate the function but doesn't work here.

Comment: This is a Fresnel integral, and indeed it converges. Look for Ahmed answer, which is enough! By the way, the result is $0.967577$.

Comment: To be precise, [it's *approximately* $0.967577$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+1+to+infinity+of+sin%281%2Fx^2%29).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$|\sin u| \le u$ for all $u \ge 0$. Your integral absolutely converges.

Comment: So in this case, using comparison test is enough to demonstrate the integral is convergent, right?

Comment: @XXWANGL yes ${}$

Answer (score 1):

You are only asked to determine the convergence or not for this generalized integral - which means that you do not have to proceed to any kind of exact calculation. Note that $\displaystyle \bigg|\sin \frac{1}{x^2}\bigg|\leq \frac{1}{x^2},~x>1$ and $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Well I started typing this without reading all of your question, but anyway you can at least evaluate this integral with known error using a Taylor series:

$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$

$$\sin \frac{1}{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{-4n-2}$$

$$\int\sin\frac{1}{x^2}\ dx=c+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!(-4n-1)}x^{-4n-1}$$

\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \sin\frac{1}{x^2}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!(4n+1)}\\
&\approx0.96757749
\end{align}